# Listbox in silverLight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a listbox in silverlight 4.

```
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="xxxxx"     Text="{Binding xxxxx}" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Quantity"       Text="{Binding Quantity}"                                   Width="30" Height="20" TextChanged="Quantity_TextChanged"></TextBox> 
                <TextBlock x:Name="UnitAmount"   Text="{Binding UnitAmount}"   Width="96"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="TotalAmount"  Text="{Binding TotalAmount}"  IsEnabled="False" Width="40"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="xxxxx"     Text="{Binding xxxxx}" Width="96"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

In this listbox i have 5 columns and in this 2nd and 4th are textboxes,as it is shown on the above code these two textboxes are used for showing quantity of an item,3rd column is used for showing the unit price of that item and the 4th column shows the total amount,that is the result which we get when the quantity is multiplied with unitamount.in this listbox textbox in put for showing quantity and total amount is because that i need to change the quantity after binding the details on listbox.my requirment is that after binding the details in the listbox i need to edit the quantity,that i have did but now i need tho change the total Amount field in the text change of quantity.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use two way bindings.
use InotifyPropertychange to refresh the TotalAmount.